# Firebase Hosting URL Redirect not redirecting string with spaces

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've moved most of my site around and while configuring redirects, folders with a space in them don't seem to redirect.

`/folder/\*.html` works

`/this folder/\*.html` does not work and is met with a 404 redirect.